# Rails nested attributes getting created but fields stay empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

These are my 2 models, nothing complicated.

```
class Invoice
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invoice_line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_line_items, allow_destroy: true
end

class InvoiceLineItem
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

This is the modified simple_form for the nested attributes.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :adress_sender %>
    <%= f.input :adress_recipient %>
    <%= f.input :status %>
    <%= simple_fields_for :invoice_line_items do |invoice_line_items_form| %>
      <%= invoice_line_items_form.input :description %>
      <%= invoice_line_items_form.input :price %>
      <%= invoice_line_items_form.input :amount %>
    <% end %>
  </div>  
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the controller according to the official documentation of rails.

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /invoices
  # GET /invoices.json
  def index
    @invoices = current_user.invoices
  end

  # GET /invoices/1
  # GET /invoices/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
    @invoice.invoice_line_items.build
  end

  # GET /invoices/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /invoices
  # POST /invoices.json
  def create
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.new(invoice_params)
    @invoice.invoice_line_items.build
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /invoices/1
  # DELETE /invoices/1.json
  def destroy
    @invoice.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to invoices_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions and check if the user has access to it.
    def set_invoice
        @invoice = current_user.invoices.find(params[:id])
        @invoice.invoice_line_items.build
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit(:adress_sender, :adress_recipient, :status, :user_id, :customer_id, invoice_line_items: [:description, :price, :amount])
    end
end
```

The invoice line items are getting created. But just the create and update date and the id. All fields like description, price and amount are empty. Also the allow_destroy seems not to work. Unfortunally there is no error in the server console :/

Edit, as suggested the console log of the creation.

```
Started POST "/invoices" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-21 15:36:42 +0200
Processing by InvoicesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mFdXPbYF+Lsb1mugWkdykBkJ1iSrzZoREL5Alw6phhQ=", "invoice"=>{"adress_sender"=>"awfawf", "adress_recipient"=>"awfgaw", "status"=>"awgag"}, "invoice_line_items"=>{"description"=>"awga", "price"=>"awgwa", "amount"=>"awg"}, "commit"=>"Create Invoice"}
  User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (7.0ms)  INSERT INTO "invoices" ("adress_recipient", "adress_sender", "created_at", "status", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["adress_recipient", "awfgaw"], ["adress_sender", "awfawf"], ["created_at", Mon, 21 Oct 2013 13:36:42 UTC +00:00], ["status", "awgag"], ["updated_at", Mon, 21 Oct 2013 13:36:42 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "invoice_line_items" ("created_at", "invoice_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 21 Oct 2013 13:36:42 UTC +00:00], ["invoice_id", 15], ["updated_at", Mon, 21 Oct 2013 13:36:42 UTC +00:00]]
   (4.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/invoices/15
Completed 302 Found in 60ms (ActiveRecord: 14.5ms)
```

Any idea or suggestion?

best regards
denym

Comment: please always post logs with your questions. you can read more about debugging your rails application here: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the already given answers, you should try `f.simple_fields_for` instead of `simple_fields_for` to represent the nested structure. Otherwise, the items built with `@invoice.invoice_line_items.build` are not filled with the form data:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :invoice_line_items do |invoice_line_items_form| %>
  <%= invoice_line_items_form.input :description %>
  <%= invoice_line_items_form.input :price %>
  <%= invoice_line_items_form.input :amount %>
<% end %>
```

Together with the altered create action (see post by Amit Sharma):

```
def create
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.create(invoice_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @invoice.save
    format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @invoice }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

and the change in "invoice_params" (see post by 8bithero):

```
def invoice_params
 params.require(:invoice).permit(:adress_sender, :adress_recipient, :status, :user_id, :customer_id, invoice_line_items_attributes: [:id, :description, :price, :amount])
end
```

this should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly something slightly irrelevant to your question - for the set_invoice call you are always creating a new invoice_line_item, even when destroying. If you are trying to include all of the invoice_line_items for a given invoice you should probably do something like this `@invoice.includes(:invoice_line_items).where(id: params[:id])` this should eager load these items.

As for your question... for the incoive_params, the `invoice_line_items` should be `invoice_line_items_attributes` (it's also good to include the :id for the update).

Try that and see if it works. Also in the create action i don't think you need to add `@invoice.invoice_line_items.build` since you have already included the params for the nested form in the command above. by doing `@invoice.invoice_line_items.build` it looks like you are simply creating ANOTHER invoice_line_item for the @invoice but without speechifying the params.

(Wrote the reply in a bit of a rush. Hope it makes sense.)

```
def create
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.new(invoice_params)
  @invoice.invoice_line_items.build
  respond_to do |format|
    if @invoice.save
      format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @invoice }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:adress_sender, :adress_recipient, :status, :user_id, :customer_id, invoice_line_items_attributes: [:id, :description, :price, :amount])
end
```

```

Side-note: Address is spelt wrong. Don't know if this will cause trouble with rail's pluralization.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following i hope it will help you.

```
def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
    @invoice.invoice_line_items.build
  end

  def create
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.create(invoice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```